# is it a security risk to have the post id # in the address bar when allowing others to edit content?

Tags: php, security

I am using this edit form to let users edit their posts/notes etc.  And the way i have it is this way:

```
 www.domain.com/editpost.php?id=390Adkw
```

So if someone plays around and changes the "390Adwk" to something like "390dkjdkljfld" it will mess up the content or worse yet, it will change someone elses content.

It will mess up because when i will do update it will be something like: Update this where id=id and it might get messed up.

So what is one way to prevent this using php?

Comment: Do you have authentication in place?

Comment: One way to prevent this using PHP is to use GET variables _ONLY_ for read, no write allowed, like it was intended. And most important have some kind of user to post relationship constraint to not allow users access or modify another user's posts.

Comment: @Shef The most RESTful way to structure URLs is like `/post/42/edit`. Embedding the id in the URL even for POST requests is perfectly "intended".

Comment: @deceze: That's a half open gate to [XSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). ["the convention has been established that the GET and HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval."](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#page-51)

Comment: @Shef GET methods is not the same as GET variables. I'm saying variables/ids are fine in the URL during POST requests, not that GET requests are POST requests.

Comment: @deceze: How are you going to get those variables out of the URL? I am guessing through rewriting, or URL parsing, which is the same as having `delete.php?id=123`. No one will stop me from embedding `<img src="/delete/myprofile/" />` on my site, or on yours if you do allow images. Once you (an authenticated user with the proper rights) reach the page with the image your profile will be gone. Thus, never take an action based on variables on a URL. Done here...

Comment: @Shef Sorry, you don't get it. Just because the id is in the URL, whether as `/foo/id` or `/foo.php?id=`, **doesn't mean I'm taking an action!** To take an action the id needs to be in the URL **and the request needs to be a POST request.** I.e. `POST /foo/id`. For `GET /foo/id` I don't *have to* and I'm not *going to* do anything. Very much done here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within the editpost page you need to do two things.  During the GET request you need to check whether or not the particular user requesting that id has access to it.

During the POST, you again need to check whether or not that particular user has the rights to edit it.

In short, don't trust that just because they passed an ID in that they have any rights to do anything with that ID.

Answer (score 4):

**Do not trust user's input.** Always check user's permission server-side and if they're not permitted to change it, don't allow them to do so

Answer (score 3):

You will need to embed the id somewhere anyway. The URL is as good a place as any. You need to have server-side checks in place that make sure a user can only edit what he's allowed to. If you do, there's no difference between the user manipulating the id directly and navigating to the record by hand and hitting the Edit button. I.e. he could edit the record either way.

Answer (score 0):

In your database, you need to link that post, comment, etc to the user that made that post. Then when sending that request check if the user that wants to edit the post is the one that created it or check if he has enough rights to edit said post.

If the user messes with the post variables, running that check will make it harder for those posts to be edited by unwanted users.